# xpath for getting all the content under a tag in one string

Tags: xpath

I want to write an XPath in Python to get the entire content of the `li` tag in order including the content of the `a` tag.

```
<li>
Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
<a target="_blank" href="/events/CES_TVR_LAKE_2014_brochure_2FEb2014.pdf">Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats</a>
", 13-15th November 2014
</li>
```

I wrote the XPath as

```
//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li//text().
```

This outputs 3 different strings:

```
Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats
", 13-15th November 2014.
```

How can i get them as a single string?

Comment: I just down-voted your question as you are giving little pieces of information in each new comment. Please make a more valuable question by editing it with all required information to properly answer it! If you ask a question and expect a useful answer you should also give all information, otherwise I seriously consider this as a waste of my time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample Python shell session:

```
>>> import lxml.html
>>> doc = lxml.html.fromstring("""<div class="inner_body_left">
... <ul>
... <li>
... Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
... <a target="_blank" href="/events/CES_TVR_LAKE_2014_brochure_2FEb2014.pdf">Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats</a>
... ", 13-15th November 2014
... </li>
... </ul>
... </div>""")
```

The simplest is to use `string()` if you know your XPath expression matches only 1 node, otherwise `string()` converts only the 1st node in the matching node-set:

```
>>> doc.xpath("string(//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li)") 
'\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\nConservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats\n", 13-15th November 2014\n'
```

Getting all text elements:

```
>>> doc.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li//text()") 
['\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\n', 'Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats', '\n", 13-15th November 2014\n']
>>> doc.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li/descendant-or-self::*/text()") 
['\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\n', 'Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats', '\n", 13-15th November 2014\n']
```

Excluding text from `a` elements (use of `/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::a)]/` instead of `//`:

```
>>> doc.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::a)]/text()") 
['\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\n', '\n", 13-15th November 2014\n']
>>> "".join(doc.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::a)]/text()") )
'\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\n\n", 13-15th November 2014\n'
>>>
```

---

Updated example with multiple elements to select from:

```
>>> doc = """<div class="inner_body_left">
... <ul>
... <li>
... Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
... <a target="_blank" href="/events/CES_TVR_LAKE_2014_brochure_2FEb2014.pdf">Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats</a>
... ", 13-15th November 2014
... </li>
... <li>
... Lake 2015: 10th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
... <a target="_blank" href="/events/CES_TVR_LAKE_2014_brochure_2FEb2014.pdf">Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats</a>
... ", 13-15th November 2015
... </li>
... </ul>
... </div>"""
>>> root = lxml.html.fromstring(doc)
>>>
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint([element.xpath("string(.)")
...                for element in root.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li")])
['\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\nConservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats\n", 13-15th November 2014\n',
 '\nLake 2015: 10th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\nConservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats\n", 13-15th November 2015\n']
>>> pprint.pprint(["".join(element.xpath("./descendant-or-self::*[not(self::a)]/text()"))
...                for element in root.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li")]
... )
['\nLake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\n\n", 13-15th November 2014\n',
 '\nLake 2015: 10th Biennial Lake Symposium on "\n\n", 13-15th November 2015\n']
>>>
```

Comment: actually i want many nodes under the div tag.All the nodes of the div tag have the similar structure.So, in this case string() does not work. And the other options give 3 different string.I want it as one string.

Comment: look at the last example using `"".join()`. Also, you can always use `element.xpath("string(.)") for element in doc.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li"))`

Comment: @user3446000 , I update my answer with an example of multiple matches under the `div` element

Comment: The updated answer works! But its inserting unnecessary spaces. I used: title=filter(lambda name: name.strip(),title) to avoid such spaces. But still, i see few spaces here n there. Is there anything else i can do?

Comment: You can try `element.xpath("normalize-space(.)")`

Answer (score 1):

The best option seems to be to simply use `string()` for what you want to achieve. It also strips comments from your XML. It converts the whole element to a xs:string:

```
//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li/string()
```

If this doesn't work for some business logic related reasons, you can always concatenate strings:

```
concat(//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li//text())
```

Comment: Bonus question: How would you ignore the text of `a`, but concat all other text nodes?

Comment: for avoiding the 'a' content, u can write the xpath as   //div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li/text()

Comment: "don't work" is not an error description - **What** does not work? And please edit your question if you have additional restrictions or more specifics.

Comment: @user3446000: not if there were other sibling elements to `a`. I guess an additional template is required, as `ul/li[not(a)]` would exclude the entire nodeset if there's an `a` element after `li`. You didn't post any python code btw., might be relevant to see your whole setup.

Comment: @dirkk, did you mean `string(//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li)`?

Comment: It shows the following error for using string() instead of text(): lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression

Comment: i use the statement like this: title=tree5.xpath("//div[@class='inner_body_left']/ul/li//text()")

Comment: @paultrmbrth No, as the statement I wrote is also a valid XPath expression (and also much more readable imho). But it seems that this particular XPath parse does not support it (i.e. is not conforming to the spec).

Comment: ah ok @dirkk, sorry. Is it XPath 2.0? when using Python lxml (which uses libxml2 -- XPath 1.0), I also get an "invalid xpath expression" error

Comment: No, it is XPath 1.0. But I guess the OP is also using lxml and I guess this is a bug in the implementation.

Answer (score 0):

See [my solution](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/36e92e02605c9fbdd39acdd792678b0f)

I've used

```
concat(substring(//div/ul/li/text()[1],1,string-length(//div/ul/li/text()[1])-1),//div/ul/li/a/text(),substring(//div/ul/li/text()[2],2))
```

for the

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><div>
  <ul>
<li>
Lake 2014: 9th Biennial Lake Symposium on "
<a target="_blank" href="/events/CES_TVR_LAKE_2014_brochure_2FEb2014.pdf">Conservation of Wetland Ecosystems in Western Ghats</a>
", 13-15th November 2014
</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

To get a single line we have to remove linebreak before  and one more after  using **substring** function